# Find whitespace in end of string using wildcards or regex

Tags: regex, search, whitespace, wildcard

I have a Resoure.resx file that I need to search to find strings ending with a whitespace. I have noticed that in Visual Web Developer I can search using both regex and wildcards but I can not figure out how to find only strings with whitespace in the end. I tried this regex but didn't work:

```
\s$
```

Can you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your code? That regex should be matching any string that has at least one whitespace character **at** the end of the string, which from your question sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Yep - it what sense did it not work?

Comment: I have no code, just using "Find and Replace" feature in Visual Web Developer, and I choosed "Regular Expressions". Is it not possible to search in resx-files?

Comment: Ah, okay. FWIW, I've answered on the basis of that, then.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd expect that to work, although since `\s` includes `\n` and `\r`, perhaps it's getting confused. Or I suppose it's *possible* (but **really** unlikely) that the flavor of regular expressions that Visual Web Developer uses (I don't have a copy) doesn't have the `\s` character class. Try this:

```
[ \f\t\v]$
```

...which searches for a space, formfeed, tab, or vertical tab at the end of a line.

If you're doing a search and replace and want to get rid of *all* of the whitespace at the end of the line, then [as RageZ points out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169442/ragez), you'll want to include a greedy quantifier (`+` meaning "one or more") so that you grab as much as you can:

```
[ \f\t\v]+$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems strange though, it searches and find strings but none of them ends with a whitespace. Maybe I should open the file in another program that handles regex and search there.

Answer (score 8):

You were almost there. adding the `+` sign means 1 characters to infinite number of characters.

This would probably make it:

```
\s+$
```

Comment: If his goal is just to find strings that have *any* whitespace at the end, there's no need for the `+`; just matching the last whitespace character is sufficient.

Comment: @TJ: yes but I think the op wants to get rid off any whitespace in the end of the line. I suppose

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this would work:

```
^.+\s$
```

Using this you'll be able to find nonempty lines that end with a whitespace character.

Comment: If a line ends with a whitespace character, it is by definition non-empty. No need for the `^.+`.

Comment: @T.J.: true; but I assumed OP wanted to find lines with some content and whitespace at the end (although `^.+` might as well match only whitespace at line beginning)