# regex check if string is end with whitespace

Tags: regex, sublimetext

```
http://www.example.com data:blaefrferter 
http://www.example.com data:blaefrferter 
http://www.example.com data:blaefrferter
```

I want get rid of the `data:blaefrferter` using regex, I've tried this ^.*$\s but it doesn't match, what is my mistake?

Comment: @anubhava what does that means?

Comment: I want to get rid of `data:blaefrferter `  using sublime text, so I search with regex

Comment: This looks like the solution to your Problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448324/find-whitespace-in-end-of-string-using-wildcards-or-regex

Comment: @anubhava sublime text search box, does language matter?

Comment: search for `\s.*$` and replace with empty string

Comment: replace `(?: +.*$)` with empty string

Answer (score 1):

In sublime enter `([^ ]*).*$` for `Find What:` and `$1` for `Replace With:`

[image]

Comment: Did you enable regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

Find what: `\s+\S+\s*`
Replace with: `NOTHING`