# Js regex allow optional line break and space indentation

Tags: javascript, regex, ruby-hash

Some relative posts:

- [Find whitespace in end of string using wildcards or regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448324/find-whitespace-in-end-of-string-using-wildcards-or-regex)
- [Match linebreaks - \n or \r\n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056306/match-linebreaks-n-or-r-n)

```js
let s = `
%nav.cf
  %ul.cf
    %li
      %a{
        :href => "#"
      } Item 1
    %li
      %a{href => "#"} Item 2
    %li
      %a{:href => "#"} Item 2
    %li
      %a{:href => "#"} Item 3

  %a{:href => "#", :id => "openup"} MENU

%h1 Basic Responsive Menu
%p Playing around and learning HAML + SCSS - Basic Responsive Menu.
`;

s.replace(/\{?[\r\n]+.*\=\>(.*)\}/g, cd=>{
  console.log(cd);
});

/*
      %a{href => "#"}

      %a{:href => "#"}

      %a{:href => "#"}


  %a{:href => "#", :id => "openup"}
*/

s.replace(/\{?[\r\n]+.*\=\>(.*)[\s]+\}/g, cd=>{
  console.log(cd);
});
/*
{
        :href => "#"
      }
*/
```

I am writing an adopter for a template engine, basically I need to extract all the `hash` insides `{}` that must have a `=>`.

The expected result are all the commented values above. which the code either returns first or the second.

```js
{
        :href => "#"
      }
%a{href => "#"}
%a{:href => "#"}
%a{:href => "#"}
 %a{:href => "#", :id => "openup"}
```

please have a look at the second expression, where I try to allow the optional line break and spaces indentation, I wonder why it gets rid of the unescaped hashes returned before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `replace`. Just use this regex for matching in `MULTILINE` mode

```bash
^[^{}\n]*{(?=[^}#]*#)[^}]*=>[^}]*}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZIURfC/2)

**Code:**

```js
let s = `
%nav.cf
  %ul.cf
    %li
      %a{
        :href => "#"
      } Item 1
    %li
      %a{href => "#"} Item 2
    %li
      %a{:href => "#"} Item 2
    %li
      %a{:href => "#"} Item 3

  %a{:href => "#", :id => "openup"} MENU

%h1 Basic Responsive Menu
%p Playing around and learning HAML + SCSS - Basic Responsive Menu.`;

console.log( s.match(/^[^{}\n]*{(?=[^}#]*#)[^}]*=>[^}]*}/gm) );
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^{}\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `{` and `}` and a line break
- `{`: Match a `{`
- `(?=[^}#]*#)`: Lookahead to make sure that we have a `#` before matching `}`
- `[^}]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `}`
- `=>`: Match a `=>`
- `[^}]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `}`
- `}`: Match a `}`

Comment: Cheers, however I need to extract the first expression with line breaks and indentations as well. ^v^

Comment: Cab you edit the question and show your expected output separately from the big code block.

Comment: Sure, have added that.

Comment: ok check my updated answer now and new demo

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird Yes I should have excluded `#` as well (edited)